# How to minimize high dV/dt device wich is connected to analog electronic load

Tags: power-electronics, high-speed, transient-suppression, electronic-load

I designed an Ac electronic load and tried to connect it to a switch mode half bridge (for testing purposes)as can be seen in the figure. Since the switch mode half bridge has high dv/dt output voltage during the transition time for turning the switched on and/ or off across the analog electronic load, the generated output current of the analog electronic load has large spikes due to internal capacitor between gate and drain of the Mosfet in analog electronic load. in this case, how can i eliminate or reduce these spikes from analog side? i would appreciate if someone could give ideas to reduce this effect.

[image]

Comment: Show the Capacitance , ESR, V and thus current you wish to limit in your schematic

Comment: Your schematic need some work... the rails are at 1v and you haven't put your ground in. What is driving M3\M4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the capacitance is really from the load (and your seeing overshoot) it might be advantageous to insert an inductor along the current path that you want to control the overshoot. The other requirements haven't been specified so I can't speculate on the value.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know what information is needed to calculate the inductor value? how can i calculate the suitable value

Comment: I'd just experimentally try some values. You could calculate the current and measure the voltage and model the circuit, that would be a lot more work than just buying some inductors 0.1uH 1uH 10uH 100uH ect and trying them. The problem is the cable parasitics are going to be hard to nail down. Make sure you also have a good path for the return current.